# yielded imports TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, bluebird, es6-promise

Based on the following code:

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");

Promise.coroutine(function* () {
  const server = yield require("./server");

  yield server.startAsync();
  console.info(`Server started on port ${server.info.port}`);
})();
```

Does TypeScript offer an `import` solution to `yield require(module)`? Or will I simply have to add

```
import server from "./server";
```

at the top of my file? Obviously `yield import module from "module"` is not valid TypeScript. I'm wondering if TS offers a similar syntax, or if I will just have to stick with ES6 requires.

In this example, I'm going to assume that the Node version is `7.x`, TypeScript is `2.3.0`, that `server.ts` has a `default export` called `server`, and that my `module` in my`tsconfig.json` is set to `es2015`, with a `target` of `es2017` (for the sake of avoiding off-topic conversation)

Comment: Try it and see ™. require is just a normal function returning any, and it should work as long as your types are correct.

Comment: The code above is, of course, valid JavaScript and valid TypeScript. I'm looking for an `import` solution instead of a `require` solution

Comment: Yes, you have to `import server from "./server"` and `yield server`. What’s wrong with that? (Well, apart from the singleton.)

Comment: Nothing wrong with that at all. I am asking for an inline solution if TypeScript offers it. If it doesn't, there's of course nothing wrong with importing at the top and yielding it later on.

Comment: … well, come to think of it, the singleton is a pretty big problem. Import `createServer` from `./server` instead, and `yield createServer()`.

Comment: Not to stray from the topic, but what about a singleton is a _big problem_? I guess I'm asking if `const myVar = yield require("myModule")` is, in your opinion, bad practice?

Comment: `import server = yield require("./server");`? Provides the benefits of type declarations while allowing your original implementation, though I'm not seeing any benefit to writing async modules. In the long run it will probably cause more issues in the future for maintenance.

Comment: Is this actually valid TypeScript? I am aware that it may provide maintenance kerfuffle later on. I really only do inline imports in the app at the server level, never in app logic. The idea here is that I want to re-import the entire app on `next()`, which is called every time a change is made to a file, or whenever the app crashes from any number of errors.

Comment: `import server = yield require("./server");` is not valid syntax, by the way. I'm getting `expected identifier` at `yield`.